# print out values from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array (
   [0] => Array ([username] => khaled [0] => khaled) 
   [1] => Array ([username] => Nariman [0] => Nariman) 
   [2] => Array ([username] => test1 [0] => test1) 
   [3] => Array ([username] => jack [0] => jack) 
   [4] => Array ([username] => mmmm [0] => mmmm) 
   [5] => Array ([username] => qqq [0] => qqq) 
   [6] => Array ([username] => wwwdwd [0] => wwwdwd) 
   [7] => Array ([username] => wddww [0] => wddww) 
   [8] => Array ([username] => maxa [0] => maxa) 
)
```

I tried `$posts['username'][0]/[0]['username']` ... didnt work!

I want to print out some values of the array, like the username for example. How to do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: Edited the question!

Comment: That would be `$posts[ $i ]['username']` instead where $i is the index of the array inside the initial array.

Comment: I've edited it to make the structure clearer. You are duplicating the username inside each nested array. The value you try to access, `$posts['username'][0]` doesn't exist. I'd suggest you read more, like in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) before moving on.

Comment: Yeah that is what I should do! Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($arr as $arrItem) {
    echo $arrItem['username'];
    echo $arrItem[0];
}
```

You can also use a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i]['username'];
    echo $arr[$i][0];
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/he6h7r

Answer (score 2):

To get a single variable (so your username in your case), you do the following:

```
$username = $posts[0]['username'];
```

This will get the username from the first nested Array in your actual array. You can modify this to get every username from each nested array by making a for loop so you get the rest of the usernames.

Answer (score 1):

On you array, key ['username'] does not exist.

If you indent the array, they read as this:

```
Array
  [0]
    [username] => khaled
    [0] => khaled
  [1]
    [username] => Nariman
    [0] => Nariman
...
```

Because this, you can read $posts[0][0] or $posts[0][username], but, you cant read $posts[username] because didn't exist.